# Bind Grid's height and width based on its child control

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have image inside grid, I wanted to set Height and width of grid to image's Source hieght+10 and width+10 respectively. I wrote below code but it is not working.

> > `<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
> >         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
> >            <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding ElementName=imagePreview, 
> >                Path=imagePreview.Source.Width}" />
> >         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
> >         <Grid.RowDefinitions >
> >            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=imagePreview, 
> >                Path=imagePreview.Source.Height}" />
> >         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
> >         <Image Name="imagePreview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
> >            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None"/>
> >
> >     </Grid>`

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What about just using the `Margin` property?:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition  Width="{Binding ElementName=imagePreview, 
           Path=imagePreview.Source.Width}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
       <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=imagePreview, 
           Path=imagePreview.Source.Height}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Name="imagePreview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None"/>     
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code to:

```
 <Grid>
     <Image Name="imagePreview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         Stretch="None" Margin="10"/>
 </Grid>
```

Use **Margin** property in the **Image** control.